# beautiful soup convert to list

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

When I use

```
page = urllib2.urlopen("https:somewebpage.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
soup.get_text()
```

I get a result that looks like a table list but its not it returns this as actual text value:

```
["<a href='/path<a>","tableNameAAA","FINISHED","SUCCEEDED","<br title='100.0'> <div class='ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' title='100.0%'> ,"0"],
["<a href='/path<a>","tableNameBBB","INPROCESS","SUCCEEDED","<br title='100.0'> <div class='ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all' title='100.0%'> ,"0"],...
```

How do I convert this to a list so I can iterate through it. I tried doing list(soup.get_text()) but when I try to iterate through it goes bananas:

```
...v', u'>', u'"', u',', u'"', u'<', u'a', u' ', u'...
```

What I expect when I iterate is :
[list1],[list2]

instead of what it is now which is "[list1],[list2]"

Comment: You can iterate through _any_ list, including those in your question. You _do not_ have  "[list1],[list2]". What exactly you do not like about your lists?

Comment: It seems like the problem is the single quotes `["<a href='/path<a>",...]` The single quote is not closed. Maybe stripping the single quotes and eval(which is generally frowned upon)

Comment: You could use ast.literal_eval - it's safer

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 using `ast.literal_eval(soup.get_text())` but it breaks right here `color:#000; background:#fefefe}`  I think because I cant seem to isloate just those tables so its eval'n the whole page

Comment: @DyZ my problem if I do have a list then if ` table = list(soup.get_text()) ` and `table[1]` should show me only 1 `["<a href='/path<a>","tableNameAAA","FINISHED","SUCCEEDED","<br ], `table and not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I just stripped all the single quotes then made a list of all the tables probably could have done this without BS but it works.